# Why isn't Empathy notifications any longer accessible via HUD in 12.10?

Tags: empathy, 12.10, hud

In Ubuntu 12.04, if someone contacted me via Empathy, I could write their name and open a chat window via HUD. This seems to have been disabled. People appear in the notification dropdown menu, but if I write their names, no relevant results appear. Have I somehow tampered with the system, or has it in fact been disabled in 12.10?

Comment: What does "HUD" mean?

Answer (score 3):

It's a regression. You can find the bug report on [Launchpad.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/indicator-appmenu/+bug/1072052)